# SignIn check Credentials from Plist

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, plist

I have a `plist` with `Array` title and `item0`,`item1`,`item2` is dictionary to store title and password of my app.now i want to check for signin process

[image: eneter here]
now i Want to check for pass and items should be matched when i press submit button to login.i Tried the below code but xcode crashes

```
-(void)authenticateCredentials 
{ 
NSMutableArray *plistArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self readFromPlist]]; 

for (int i = 0; i< [plistArray count]; i++) 
{ 
 if ([[[plistArray   objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"pass"]isEqualToString:emailTextFeild.text] && [[[plistArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"]isEqualToString:passwordTextFeild.text]) 
{ 
NSLog(@"Correct credentials"); 
} 

 } 
 }
```

and

```
-(NSArray*)readFromPlist
 {
   NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
  NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XYZ.plist"];

   NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

   NSArray *valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

   return valueArray;

 }
```

the xcode gets crashs ..please check in  `-(void)authenticateCredentials` where i am incorrect?

"Edit" 
Crash when I select the `submit` button,Its giving output in nslog correct but crash then , with errorr

```
 2012-12-07 16:52:54.025 NavTutorial[3029:f803] emailEntry: emailemail@gmail.com
 2012-12-07 16:52:54.057 NavTutorial[3029:f803] passwordEntry: abcd
 2012-12-07 16:52:54.081 NavTutorial[3029:f803] Correct credentials
 2012-12-07 16:52:54.081 NavTutorial[3029:f803] Correct credentials
 2012-12-07 16:52:54.082 NavTutorial[3029:f803] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68e9c30
 2012-12-07 16:52:54.083 NavTutorial[3029:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68e9c30'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x14d7052 0x11c2d0a 0x14d8ced 0x143df00 0x143dce2 0x3e71 0x14d8ec9 0x3735c2 0x37355a 0x418b76 0x41903f 0x417e22 0x39893f 0x398c56 0x37f384 0x372aa9 0x1bcdfa9 0x14ab1c5 0x1410022 0x140e90a 0x140ddb4 0x140dccb 0x1bcc879 0x1bcc93e 0x370a9b 0x252d 0x24a5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: While I haven't looked at why your code is crashing, the first thing that I saw is that you are storing user credentials in a plist.  This is a **very bad thing** and you should not do it.  See SO questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app for recommended methods of storing user credentials.

Comment: your code is working correctly. I cross checked it, may be its some thing to do with the textfields.

Comment: @Pranav ya I dont know y this problem is coming

Comment: you are certainly doing some other thing wrong as this code works fine at my side ...

Comment: please attach the error log

Comment: there is something else i guess the code is good and working put a break point and then debug i guess you have some other objects also than the dictionary in your plistArray...try deleting the app and then run again.

Comment: I got the problem ,Its in the loop ,firstly time its shows correct credentials ..then again goes to the loop ..again prints correct credentials...then 3rd time the error comes which is above...and If write Return; to complete its moves outside the loop..that is been solved now :)

Comment: Very bad to store credentials in plist. plist files are visible to everyone once your app is compiled. You should be store credentials and such using Keychain which is encrypted.

Comment: @spider1983 did u check problem in chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was my fault actually .. the code is in code so executes again and again ..then crashes...but when i put `Return` to exit from the `for` loop ...its works fine...small but powerful mistake.

Comment: i told ya the code is fine its just the value which is in array causing the problem you can also nslog the plistArray after initializing in your code just above the for loop you can see the value stored in it, then debug it likewise

Comment: ya i will check that have some work will see that at home ..don't worry its a minor bug,not so serious.

Comment: @spider1983 sorry to disturb you actually need to submit.but did you check my code

Comment: sorry pal was out of station so was not able to take look on the code.Will see that today night...i am a bit busy with the works.

Comment: @spider1983 Check your mail id .. i mailed my doubt in simpler way . .

Comment: i think you are busy..i wil not disturb u again

Comment: hey pal ya i am a bit busy rt now for my own projects i will see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Peter M, you shouldn't store them locally, at least in plain text.
It would help a lot if you could post the error stack, so we could see what's failing.